# Extrema of $x+y+z$ subject to $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ and $2x + z = 1$ using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the extrema of $x+y+z$ subject to $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ and $2x + z = 1$ using Lagrange multipliers.

So I set it up:

$$
1 = 2x\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 \\
1 = -2y\lambda_1 \\
1 = \lambda_2
$$

Plug in for $\lambda_2$:

$$
1 = 2x\lambda_1 + 2 \\
1 = -2y\lambda_1 \\
$$

So we work with:

$$
1 = 2x\lambda_1 + 2 \\
1 = -2y\lambda_1 \\
1 = x^2 - y^2 \\
1 = 2x + z
$$

After some algebra I got $x = y$ as a solution but that's impossible because of the constraint $1 = x^2 - y^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: WA says [there are no extrema](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize+x%2By%2Bz+subject+to+x%5E2-y%5E2%3D1+and+2x%2Bz%3D1). Did you copy the problem correctly?

Comment: But WA lists the local extrema (just not the global extrema), which is why I am confused. I am 100% the problem is correct, direct from the textbook. http://i.imgur.com/kHSX303.png (In case I am blind and someone sees I made a typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraints define two curves in ${\mathbb R}^3$ as follows: The constraint $x^2-y^2=1$ defines a hyperbolic cylinder $Z$ consisting of two sheets, which can be parametrized as follows:
$$(t,z)\mapsto(\pm\cosh t,\sin t, z)\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty, \ -\infty<z<\infty)\ .$$
Intersecting these two sheets with the plane $z=1-2x$ produces thw two curves
$$\gamma_\pm:\ t\mapsto(\pm\cosh t,\sinh t, 1\mp2\cosh t)\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
The pullback of $f(x,y,z):=x+y+z$ to $\gamma_\pm$ computes to
$$\phi(t)=1+\sinh t\mp\cosh t\ ,$$
so that we obtain
$$\phi'(t)=\cosh t\mp\sinh t=e^{\mp t}>0\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
This shows that there are no conditionally stationary points of $f$ on the two curves, and explains why Lagrange's method didn't produce any solutions.

Comment: i noticed that you also solved problems in elemente der matematik journal, are you still doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the constraints: you can simplify them in
$$ y=\pm\sqrt{y^2+1}, \qquad z=\mp 2\sqrt{y^2+1}+1$$
for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
In this way you can convert the constrained optimization in two unconstrained optimizations: substitute the two solutions in the objective function and you will find 
$$- \sqrt{y^2+1}+y+1, \qquad \sqrt{y^2+1}+y+1.$$

These two real functions are monotone increasing so they don't possess any stationary point.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** There is no extremas with the current situation...So I slightly changed one of the

"constraints" to:

$x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$, and to show you how to solve if using **one parameter** $LM$ method.

$x + y + z = x + y + (1 - 2x) = y - x + 1$, subject to: $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$.

Define $f(x,y) = -x + y + 1$, and $g(x,y) = x^2 - 2y^2$. Then:

$\nabla f = \lambda\cdot \nabla g \to (-1,1) = (2x\lambda,-4y\lambda)$. Thus:

$-1 = 2x\lambda$

$1 = -4y\lambda$.

Add the above equations: $2\lambda(x - 2y) = 0 \to \lambda = 0$ or $x = 2y$. But $\lambda$ cannot be $0$, so $x = 2y$, and with $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$ we get:

$4y^2 - 2y^2 = 1 \to 2y^2 = 1 \to y = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So $x = 2y = \pm \sqrt{2}$.

$f_{min} = f(\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and

$f_{max} = f(-\sqrt{2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{2}}$